# How can I create a screenshot in Winrt applications?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

In my Metro application, how can I programmatically create a screen capture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, in this version, the necessary WriteableBitmap.Render method is not yet implemented. Without this, a screenshot is not possible.